# How do client anti-cheats prevent mock reports?

Tags: anti-cheat, hacks

I'm mostly thinking about Riot's Vanguard and (what I think Valve does) with different bait memory addresses.  How do these anti-cheat systems actually verify that if a packet is sent that it is actually from the anti-cheat on the client and not a faux signal?  What immediately comes to my mind is that each request contains the current time and is then encrypted.  But even if obfuscated, couldn't someone given enough time in Ghidra find the encryption keys(or how to request the encryption keys)?

Comment: You actually never want to prevent them. The usual practise is to detect them and after some time (the after the time is important to not give an indication what triggered the detect) ban the account.

Comment: @Zibelas So basically have like "trap" data so its hard for a hacker to know what they can safely alter?

Comment: Yes, because if you give feedback right away, it is way easier to adjust the 3rd party software. If the publisher has a few weeks to gather who is using a 3rd party tool, you are way more effective compared to make any input invalid. Invalid input can be fixed quite easy when you can try as often as you want until the game accepts it.

Comment: The practices Zibelas describes are covered in a bit more depth in this past Q&A thread, [How to prevent automation-type cheating?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/157446/39518) Your assessment that a sufficiently-dedicated hacker could forge any client-side signing is accurate: that's why we have the mantra ["The client is in the hands of the enemy"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22client+is+in+the+hands+of+the+enemy%22). If you want to escape this, the server needs to be validating play traces step by step, checking the client's work, not trusting it in any way.

Comment: See also: [Verifying client file integrity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/156750/39518)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "How does X technology work" questions don't match the GDSE Q&A format.

Comment: @liggiorgio but I'm not asking how the technology generally works, even if that is what was partially included in the answer.  I was asking specifically how packets sent from an anticheat client are verified.